# Piping CSV into Ruby code - how to?

Tags: ruby, csv, pipe

I want to pipe a csv file into a ruby script

e.g. 
    my_file.csv | my_ruby_script.rb

What is the correct code to use?

I've tried using this code but it doesn't work.

```
  #!/usr/bin/env ruby 

  require 'csv'
  require 'awesome_print'

  CSV.parse(STDIN.read, :headers => true) do |row|
      ap row.to_hash
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, the code is in test1.rb

This is an example with windows, type displays the file, you should use the Linux equivalent if you use that OS.

```
type test.csv|test1.rb
```

gives

{
     "test1" => "test1",
    " test2" => " test2"
}
{
     "test1" => "test1",
    " test2" => " test2"
}

where the csv is

```
test1, test2
test1, test2
test1, test2
```